# Custom file extensions as ASP.NET in IIS?

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, .htaccess, asp.net

I have Apache 2.2, and it's got modaspdotnet installed - the 2.2 version.

I followed the advice at [Configuring ASP.NET MVC2 on Apache 2.2 using mod_aspdotnet](https://serverfault.com/questions/132846/configuring-asp-net-mvc2-on-apache-2-2-using-mod-aspdotnet), and the server works basically very well.

However, I'm trying to create custom extensions (e.g. file.customname, instead of file.aspx), similar to how Apache/PHP/htaccess can handle this. (I think it's mod_rewrite or .htaccess, forgotten which now!)

What would I do to get these custom file types (all serving .NET files) working?

The extensions are given custom names by me, simply for testing purposes

This is a tourism site [a testing one, btw], and it's working OK on localhost for basic pages, but I wanted to know how to do this.

How would I go about this? I've had a look on Google etc. but custom HTTP handlers was all I could really find!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to configure handlers for this, why not just use a rewrite. In your web.config add the following to your `<system.webServer>` section:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="Rewrite custom ext" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)\.customname$" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
<system.webServer>
```

This will rewrite:

```
http://example.com/somepage.customname -> http://example.com/somepage.aspx
```

If you're trying to use custom extensions in an ASP.NET MVC application then you could use a route:

```
{controller}/{action}.customname/{id}
```